Handler dispatch failed: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.Object org.hibernate.ScrollableResults.get(int)'
Spring Boot 3.3.3

How to fix the issue?
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public Map<Integer, QuotesCountersDto> loansWithQuotesCounters(LoansWithQuotesCountRequestParams params) {
    companyService.checkCompanyExists(params.getCompanyId());
    userService.checkUserHasValidCompany(params.getUserId(), params.getCompanyId());

    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();

    var cq = cb.createTupleQuery();
    Root<LoanEntity> loanRoot = cq.from(LoanEntity.class);
    Join<LoanEntity, QuoteEntity> quoteJoin = loanRoot.join("quote", JoinType.INNER);

    List<Predicate> predicates = getLoanNotExpiredCondition(cb, loanRoot, params);

    cq.multiselect(loanRoot.get("loanId"), cb.count(quoteJoin.get("id")))
            .where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]))
            .groupBy(loanRoot.get("loanId"), loanRoot.get("createdOn"))
            .orderBy(params.isOlder() ? cb.desc(loanRoot.get("createdOn")) : cb.asc(loanRoot.get("createdOn")));

    var query = entityManager.createQuery(cq);
    query.setMaxResults(params.getLimit());

    var result = query.getResultList();

    Map<Integer, Long> loansWithAllQuotesCount = result.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    tuple -> tuple.get(0, Integer.class),
                    tuple -> tuple.get(1, Long.class)
            ));

    Map<Integer, Long> loansWithUnreadQuotesCount = getLoansWithUnreadQuotesCount(loansWithAllQuotesCount.keySet(), params);

    return loansWithAllQuotesCount.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    Map.Entry::getKey, e -> {
                        Long unreadQuotesCount = loansWithUnreadQuotesCount.get(e.getKey());
                        Long totalQuotesCount = e.getValue();
                        return QuotesCountersDto.builder()
                                .totalQuotesCount(Objects.nonNull(totalQuotesCount) ? totalQuotesCount : 0)
                                .unreadQuotesCount(Objects.nonNull(unreadQuotesCount) ? unreadQuotesCount : 0)
                                .build();
                    }
            ));
}

